# Close (other) reasons are duplicated for each one someone's submitted

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, android-app

There appears to be duplicate (Other) reasons showing on the close dialog in the Android App. Not sure if this is because someone has already registered a Close Vote with a custom comment:

[image: Dodgy screenshot]

**Device:** Nexus 5
**Offending Question:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040012/improve-a-php-developer-profile-having-2-5-year-experience

Comment: Looks like it's taking existing close votes with custom reason, but fails to show the actual reason that was written, hence looking exactly the same as the default.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, that's what I thought. Additionally, not sure if relevant, but it takes a long time to load this dialog - about 8 seconds on my 80Mb fibre connection over WiFi to the phone.

Comment: More likely a bug with the API not returning the correct text for custom off-topic reasons.

Comment: This same problem exists in iOS, so @animuson probably hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Was someone just mean and using a custom close reason of `Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in prod.

Fix is described in [Custom close votes broken in iOS app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295336/custom-close-votes-broken-in-ios-app/314201#314201)

Answer (score 4):

This is still a problem in Android app v1.0.48. (Device: HTC One, Android 4.4.3.)

This shows up when someone's submitted a custom off-topic close reason for closing a question. It also makes it impossible to *select* that custom off-topic close reason and vote to close for that reason.

On the site, as 3kers may be aware, custom off-topic close reasons occur in the close vote pane. That doesn't happen here.

I ran into this today in a question on Board Games: [Where can I buy Magic: The Gathering cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18894/where-can-i-buy-magic-the-gathering-cards) It's a shopping question. Someone had submitted a custom close reason already (it's the upvoted comment toward the end), which meant I wouldn't have to write my own and could vote for that reason.

(You can click any of the below images for a full size view.)

> [image]

But if I go to Close → Off Topic, I see the following. (To those noticing the clock, this *was* actually taken before the other two screenshots.)

> [image]

Both of those last two options are identical, and both took me to the following pane:

> [image]

This left me unable to vote to close for that custom off topic reason via the app altogether.